# Is there a way I can get a code block always visible while scrolling in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

That's all, sometimes I miss I could do that while working on different parts of a kinda long  script or whatever... So I think it'd be nice if, as we can do in a spread sheet by fixing a row for example, we could quickly define certain part of the code we want always visible and then can scroll to any other part of the script while still being able to see such "fixed" lines of code as a reference, copy, etc.

It seemed to me that it could be an already existing feature, but I've been not able to find anything... not even an extension, but maybe someone here knows? Well, I hope it makes sense and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Hard to guess for how large "sticky" portion of code you are actually aiming, but if it is just, say, function "signature line" or nesting header in general, you may try experimental "***Editor sticky scroll***" (`editor.experimental.stickyScroll.enabled`) feature that was just released in VSC v1.70:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_editor-sticky-scroll

[image: Visual Studio Code document area with breadcrumb and TypeScript class with nested function scrolling; while bodies of functions slides under top border of the editor, lines where functions and classes start remains "stuck" until their ending bracket reaches them during scrolling and only then they leave the viewport.]

Comment: Yeah, I was aware about that addition, but decided not activating cause I saw it like a little redundant since you already can get the info it brings you from just above (unless I'm missing something, of course). Anyway it wouldn't let me see more code than the class/function/whatever declaration line, so I'm afraid not what I was looking for... But thanks!

Comment: Thought so. Anyway, maybe add some real-world-ish example of your use-case and ideal outcome you imagine to your question.

Comment: Of course, I basically imagined something like select a block of code, let's say 8 lines i.e., then I press something around line numbers or folding column (or a shortcut) and those selected lines simply get "fixed" just like in your GIF but no matter how much I scroll down/up, so those lines remain visible while working in another part of the script until I press again the button/mark/shortcut or whatever. It seemed to me a practical (and less screen wasting) way for quick little tasks than go splitting editors, but as I said having already such splitting feature I might be asking too much...

Answer (score 1):

How about spliting the editor?

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I clarified by answering to my own question that splitting editors was probably the closer I could get to what I was looking for, but the answer was deleted since it should has been posted as a comment (sorry, still too new here ). Anyway I thought I didn't lose anything asking, just in case another way more similar to what I explained in my other comments was possible, via extensions or whatever... So, yes, if nobody knows another way, I'm afraid "Split Editor" is going to be the right answer. Well, thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 0):

click on `ctrl + shift + p`

Then paste this command `Editor sticky scroll`

It will fix this problem.